# How to get item from JSON and use if/else to state what should follow?

Tags: javascript, html, json

Is it possible to get the AGE from the regular results[0].AGE? I cant seem to find a way to get the value in the first place. Also, is it possible to have an if statement that does `.then(vs => document.getElementById('GBPM').innerHTML = vs.toFixed(2))` when the age is under 10 and to do `.then(vs => document.getElementById('GBPM').innerHTML = "-Offline-"` when the age is over 10?

I have tired to use regular if else, but nothing is working. I also tired to get the AGE value, but no success.

```
const getData5 = () =>
                        fetch('https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13183')
                            .then(serverResponse => serverResponse.json())
                            .then(apiResultObject => apiResultObject.results[0])
                            .then(result => JSON.parse(result.Stats))
                            .then(stat => stat.v)
        
                        getData5()
                            .then((response) => {
                                console.log(response)
                                if(response.AGE <= 10){
                                    let vs = response.Stats.v;
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').innerHTML = vs.toFixed(2);
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').innerHTML = aqiFromPM(vs,'RBAQI','RBPM',"RBLVL")
                                }else if(response.AGE >= 10){
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                    document.getElementById('RBLVL').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBLVL').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                }
                            });
```

The return value is `1` using the link in the `fetch` attribute.

NEW ERROR CODE:

```
const getData6 = () =>
                        fetch('https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=13183')
                            .then(serverResponse => serverResponse.json())
                            .then(arr => {
                            const wanted = arr.results[0]
                            wanted.Stats = JSON.parse(wanted.Stats);
                            return wanted
                            })

                        getData6()
                            .then(item =>{
                            console.log(`Age ${item.AGE}`);
                            console.log(`Stats.v ${item.Stats.v}`)
                            console.log(`PM2_5Value ${item.PM2_5Value}`)
                            })
                            .then((response) => {
                                if(item.AGE <= 10){
                                    let vs = item.PM2_5Value;
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').innerHTML = vs.toFixed(2);
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').innerHTML = aqiFromPM(vs,'RBAQI','RBPM',"RBLVL")
                                }else if(item.AGE >= 10){
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                    document.getElementById('RBLVL').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBLVL').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: Can you show your apiResultObject

Answer (score 0):

The `AGE` property of each object is a sibling of `Stats`, not a child.

So you need to return the whole `results[0]` object

```js
const getData4 = () =>
  fetch('https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=22269')
  .then(serverResponse => serverResponse.json())
  .then(arr => {
    const wanted = arr.results[0]
    wanted.Stats = JSON.parse(wanted.Stats);
    return wanted
  })

getData4().then(item =>{
  console.log(`Age ${item.AGE}`);
  console.log(`Stats.v ${item.Stats.v}`)
  console.log(`PM2_5Value ${item.PM2_5Value}`)
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the ```console.log``` a variable where I can use it to compare the if/else that @RoneelParalkar gave?

Comment: Certainly...I am simply showing you how to get the AGE from each object in array. Are you wanting all ages or just the first one?

Comment: I need the ```AGE``` that is in ```results.[0].AGE``` on the JSON input

Comment: OK so get rid of the rest of the array and just return the first object in array?

Comment: Yes please. Is there a way to do it with out the array?

Comment: Just return `results[0]` then. Not sure why the rest of the array exists or is being ignored

Comment: That is what I have in my original code. I only need it for the first results array, and I only need the PM 2.5 value and the AGE value.

Comment: OK see update. I am only logging the values...you can add in the rest of the `if/else`

Comment: Perfect. How do you make the ```console.log``` into variables?

Comment: `if(item.AGE <= 10)`

Comment: @cherliefl Can you please look at my new code in problem? I am getting an error.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help on this

Comment: Create a demo in jsfiddle.net if you have issues so it can be forked and debugged using runnable code

Comment: You added an extra `then()` ... use the `item` in the one where the logs are being done

Comment: Not sure why. That url still working in my answer when I run it

Comment: I have updated original post with snippet. Your code is under getData6 and is being outputted to the last row in the table: Rubicon Bay. Please let me know if I did something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You need to return the Promise from the fetch, after that you can use then on getData4()
Try the following code.Hope it helps.Forgot to change age to AGE

```
const getData5 = () => {
  return fetch('https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=22269')
    .then(serverResponse => serverResponse.json())
    .then(apiResultObject => apiResultObject.results[0])
}

getData5()
                            .then((item) => {
                                console.log(item)
                                if(item.AGE <= 10){
                                    let vs = item.Stats.v;
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').innerHTML = vs.toFixed(2);
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').innerHTML = aqiFromPM(vs,'RBAQI','RBPM',"RBLVL")
                                }else if(item.AGE >= 10){
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBPM').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBAQI').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                    document.getElementById('RBLVL').innerHTML = "-Offline-";
                                    document.getElementById('RBLVL').style.backgroundColor = "#808080";
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: The arrow function has an implicit return when no `{}` code block is used

Comment: @RoneelParalkar That worked thank you. However, the if statement is is not working correctly. Using ```console.log(response)```, it comes up as 1, however, it completes the code in the else statement. I changed the code based on my needs and have updated it above.

Comment: `.age` needs to be `.AGE` and Stats is a JSON string until it gets parsed

Comment: Please check now with capitalized AGE property.let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: why are 2 'then' on getData6 function.use only 1st one...and write all the code inside that

Comment: I was working on that code with another person. It is under CODE SNIP OF IF ELSE:

Answer (score -1):

checkout how `Promise` (and async in general) works. `then` is beeing invoked only once (and it's consumed)

```
  const getData4 = () =>
          fetch('https://www.purpleair.com/json?show=22269')
              .then(serverResponse => {
                     var json = serverResponse.json();
                     if (json.yourAgeField > 10){ ...set GBPM }
                     else { ..set -Offline- }
                })
```

Comment: This is not right. How is OP going to call `getData4().then()`? Also `serverResponse.json()` returns a promise. See `fetch()` docs

Comment: The question is how he can implement an if else statement for some age property and not if the function is invoked like this: `getData(){ return fetch(..url)}` or like this: `getData(){fetch(..url).then(..set innerHTML )}`.

Comment: Fine but you have to use the `serverResponse.json()` promise correctly and if you open the url will see the data is an array. Your code will throw errors and doesn't return anything in the `then()`